# How to Solve "Wowza Streaming Engine Manager could not connect to the Wowza Streaming Engine service(http://localhost:8087)."

Tags: wowza

How to Solve "Wowza Streaming Engine Manager could not connect to the Wowza Streaming Engine service(http://localhost:8087)."

I installed Wowza Streaming Engine 4.7.1, but I try to login show error.

screen shot : [image: http://s1.postimg.org/r9rjqsr1b/screenshot_61.png]

**Wowza Streaming Engine Manager could not connect to the Wowza Streaming Engine service(http://localhost:8087). Verify that the Wowza Streaming Engine service has started and is running.**

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you to start the services on the server.  This can be done by starting the services via the system or by running Wowza in standalone mode.

SERVICES:

On Windows, open a command prompt in administrator mode, and enter `services.msc`.  Then locate the  Wowza Streaming Engine and Wowza Streaming Engine Manager services and start each of them.

On Linux, open a terminal and enter `sudo service WowzaStreamingEngine start` and `sudo service WowzaStreamingEngineManager start`.

STANDALONE:

On Windows, open a command prompt in administrator mode, and `cd` to the `bin` directory of the Wowza installation.  Run `startup.bat`.  Then, `cd` to the `manager/bin` directory, and run `startmgr.bat`.

On Linux, open a terminal, and `cd` to the `bin` directory of the Wowza installation. Run `sudo ./startup.sh`.  Then, `cd` to the `manager/bin` directory, and run `./startmgr.sh`.

Comment: but Wowza Streaming Engine service not start , its show error ?

Comment: You can look at the error logs at `/logs` and `/manager/logs` and see if there's anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure, I am the Developer Community Manager at Wowza. This is what we suggest you do when you get that error:

Verify that the Wowza Streaming Engine service has started and is running. Why? By default, Wowza Streaming Engine server software and Streaming Engine Manager install as system services and both should start automatically when you start your computer.

Troubleshooting:

Confirm that Wowza Streaming Engine is running:
Open a web browser and enter the URL: http://[wowza-ip-address]:1935/ServerVersion ([wowza-ip-address] is the IP address or domain of the Wowza Streaming Engine server.)

If Wowza Streaming Engine installed correctly, the browser displays the Wowza Streaming Engine version number. If not, make sure that the server is running and that TCP port 1935 is open on your router, firewall, and/or software firewall (iptables on Linux).

Make sure that you have the appropriate ports open to access the Wowza Streaming Engine and Wowza Streaming Engine Manager services, and that HTTP requests are being routed correctly through these ports. See our website ans search "Streaming Engine ports."

If the appropriate ports aren't open, check your server's firewall configuration to make sure it isn't blocking them.

After opening ports, you must stop and restart Wowza Streaming Engine and Wowza Streaming Engine Manager. Please review how to start and stop Engine instructions.

Hope this helps you and anyone else. This is a commonly asked question in Wowza Support.